# Scrolling from one div to another using jQuery (should be easy)

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

All I want to do is scroll from the first div to the second div (both have class 'question') when I press the button with class `next_btn`. I feel like my jQuery is correct, however, when I click nothing happens.

**Note:** I will be adding many more questions after so I'd rather not use an id for every question and every button.

Error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

```js
$(".next_btn").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).parents().next('.question').offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-sm-12 logo">
      <img src="q.png" height="350px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 buttons" style="left:0px; text-align:center;">
    <button class="btn next_btn">NEXT</button><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-sm-12 logo">
      <img src="q.png" height="150px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-12 buttons" style="left:0px; text-align:center;">
      <button class="btn next_btn">NEXT</button><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code you pasted works fine, there is no issue with your code except if you click on the second/last button

Comment: The first button gives me an error too.

Comment: `NEXT` button 1 scrolls the page to image 2 but `NEXT` 2 will error as theres nothing to scroll, just remove the second button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error when you click the last button since he has no `.question` next of it, so`$(this).parents().next('.question')` return `undefined`,  you could add a condition like the snippet shows.

```
//Get the next question
var next_question = $(this).parents().next('.question');

// Check if the question exist them animate
if (next_question.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: next_question.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

```js
$(".next_btn").click(function() {
  var next_question = $(this).parents().next('.question');

  if (next_question.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: next_question.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="question">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-sm-12 logo">
      <img src="q.png" height="350px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 buttons" style="left:0px; text-align:center;">
    <button class="btn next_btn">NEXT</button><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-sm-12 logo">
      <img src="q.png" height="150px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-12 buttons" style="left:0px; text-align:center;">
      <button class="btn next_btn">NEXT</button><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-sm-12 logo">
      <img src="q.png" height="150px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-12 buttons" style="left:0px; text-align:center;">
      <button class="btn next_btn">NEXT</button><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-sm-12 logo">
      <img src="q.png" height="150px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-12 buttons" style="left:0px; text-align:center;">
      <button class="btn next_btn">NEXT</button><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: so you downvote and vote to delete mine and then copy my answer, well done

Comment: I voted the delete by mistake when I was trying to remove mine, And I didnt't downvoted.

Comment: I afraid that I have to do if you didn't remove yours :(

Comment: I'll remove it now, I just want to prove that it's not mine, I didn't downvote for revenge, I downvote the unuseful posts...

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help

Comment: Glad we could help @FezAbbas